# The mouse event GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y) gives wrong values for ListView control

Tags: c#, listview, select, click, mouseevent

Strange behavior with C# (VS 2010) ListView Control mouse click event (items are without checkbox):

```
private void m_ListView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // Returning some times wrong values
        ListViewItem lvi = m_ListView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y); 

        //.... more logic here
    }
}
```

After I clicked the item, and immediately I moved the mouse down or up, some other item is getting selected instead of what is intended;

I debugged and came to know that e.X, e.Y is capturing WRONG values. When I click and leave the mouse pointer unmoved, it's working fine. But if I clicked and immediately moved to another row, one of that row is getting selected instead.

Questions:

- Is this a known issue with ListView mouse events?
- Is there any other way to retrieve correct coordinates for the mouse events?

This is an enterprise level project, where performance is very important. We have written original code for all mouse events like up, down, doubleclick, mouseclick, itemcheck etc.

-Karthik

Comment: "Very urgent" and screaming (using CAPSLOCK everywhere) will quickly lead to downvotes, and definitely not help finding people willing to answer ;)

Comment: Does your code for the MouseUp event interact with the ListView?

Comment: @karthik I edited your question to keep things easy and clean. People hate to read QUesTIONS WITH CAPITALS and screaming URGENT! URGENT! We all dedicate *our* free time to help others, we don't get paid, so please appreciate it.

Comment: @oleksii I was doing the same, I believe I merged our efforts correctly now. But really, Karthik, don't use that kind of writing again, it distracts, has no bearing here, costs a lot of time to rectify to proper text and probably results in the reverse of what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Understood Guys; Sorry; Thanks

Comment: @Abel yeah I noticed that. Good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListViewItem lvi = m_ListView.FocusedItem;
```

That should work to get the item that was just clicked (Focused)

```
m_ListView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
```

Would get the item at the mouse location, which is why it changes when you move the mouse quickly away, if you want the item that you just clicked, `m_ListView.FocusedItem` should work fine

Comment: Thank you for quick response; I will try now and let you know back

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider what "wrong value" constitutes. The click-event is a high-level event and the moment the code is executed is not necessarily equal to where the mouse is at that time. The stored coordinates of that click event are from the *moment the user clicked the button*. If you continue to move the mouse, the coordinates inside the event will be unequal to the coordinates of the mouse at that same moment.

You say that you handle all mouse events. If it is for performance, consider using the build-in mechanisms of the control, these are optimized for speed and accuracy. It's hard to improve on 10 years of development (the control, through various earlier incarnations, has seen quite some development time at MS).

If you really need the utmost speed, write your own control instead from scratch. Use low-level mouse events to get the best available information.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, the MouseClick event is generated by the *MouseUp* event.  All click events work like that.  Pushing the button, moving the mouse and releasing the button thus always gives the location where you released the button, not where you pushed it.

You would need to use the MouseDown event instead.